# Keyboard input in number input field different from using +/- spinner

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I have a number type html input field. Typing by keyboard into the input field, for example the number five, has the form perform an action (update a totals counter via ajax).

However, using the +/- spinner buttons on the field does not trigger this behavior.

I think it may be how the form was originally coded; that keyboard inputs are what triggers the ajax call. Maybe. I sure as heck don't have the skills to dive into the exact workings of the form - it's part of a plugin for an e-commerce platform and I think I should not mess with the original code; rather tweak the functionality.

I'm asking here after hours of trying to learn but being stumped. Is there a way to have the input number change via the spinner to mimic keypress behavior?

Thank you.

Tried to update the value attribute of the input when spinner used. Made custom +/- buttons that change the input field value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event listener `change`.

**Example:**

```js
document.getElementById('age').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="age" type="number">
```

Comment: Thank you. This logs the current input, but does not trigger whatever it is that keyboard presses trigger. The problem remains: only keyboard presses register as actionable when using the form.

Comment: @MainioMooses that was a basic example of how to go on. I don't know what your code does. If you want more info, please share us your code.